# How to Find App Pool Recycles in Event Log

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have configured an app pool in IIS 7.5 to recycle when the memory usage goes above a certain level. I have also configured it to log this information.

Where in the event log should I look for this?

I have tried filtering based on the source being all the IIS items, e.g. 'IIS-W3SVC-WP', 'IIS-IISManager', and all the rest, but nothing.

I can see that it is adding in the items from the 'IIS-Configuration' log too which I enabled. But still nothing.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

It seemed quite hard to find this information, but eventually, I came across [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17630/which-event-log-file-does-iis-7-app-pool-log-to) 
You have to look at the 'System' event log, and filter by the WAS source. 
Here is [more info about the WAS (Windows Process Activation Service)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/features-of-the-windows-process-activation-service-was)

Comment: I had the same issue. Mayby interesting to mention is that you have to configure in which cases the app pool recycle event is logged. By default it's in a couple of cases, not all of them. You can do that in IIS > app pools > select the app pool > advanced settings > expand generate recycle event log entry

Comment: @BlackHawkDesign You should consider turning your comment into a full-fledged answer (maybe even with screenshot of the relevant settings ;-) this info is rather critical to successfully detecting when an app pool actually gets recycled.

Answer (score 32):

As it seems impossible to filter the XPath message data (it isn't in the XML to filter), you can also use powershell to search:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName System | Where-Object {$_.Message -like "*recycle*"}
```

From this, I can see that the event Id for recycling seems to be 5074, so you can filter on this as well. I hope this helps someone as this information seemed to take a lot longer than expected to work out.

This along with @BlackHawkDesign comment should help you find what you need.

> I had the same issue. Maybe interesting to mention is that you have to
>   configure in which cases the app pool recycle event is logged. By
>   default it's in a couple of cases, not all of them. You can do that in
>   IIS > app pools > select the app pool > advanced settings > expand
>   generate recycle event log entry – BlackHawkDesign Jan 14 '15 at 10:00

Answer (score 9):

**As link-only answers are not preferred, I will just copy and paste the content of the link of the accepted answer**

---

It is definitely **System Log**.

**Which Log file?** Well -- you can check the physical path by right-clicking on the System Log (e.g. Server Manager | Diagnostics | Event Viewer | Windows Logs). The default physical path is `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\System.evtx`.

You can create a **Custom Filter** and filter by "Source: WAS" to quickly see only entries generated by IIS.

You may need first to enable logging of such even for a specific App Pool -- by default App Pool has only 3 recycle events out of 8 enabled. To change it using GUI: II S Manager | Application Pools | Select App Pool -> Advanced Settings | Generate Recycle Event Log Entry.

Answer (score 9):

**IIS version 8.5 +**

To enable Event Tracing for Windows for your website/application

1. Go to *Logging* and ensure either ***ETW event only*** or ***Both log file and ETW event*** ...is selected.

[image]

2. Enable the desired Recycle logs in the Advanced Settings for the Application Pool:

[image]

3. Go to the default Custom View: *WebServer* filters IIS logs:

**Custom Views > ServerRoles > Web Server**

[image]

4. ... or *System* logs:

**Windows Logs > System**