# How to detect Application pool re-starts in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

The product runs lot of application pools in IIS on Windows. Goal is to be able to detect any IIS application pool crashes and generate alerts.

I'm thinking of writing a C# .NET Service that can detect specific IIS application pool crashes.

Which C# .NET package allows Windows system events to be trapped in C# code and responded to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984604/how-to-find-app-pool-recycles-in-event-log

Comment: Hi @agargi, could this help ? https://serverfault.com/questions/98726/how-can-we-create-a-log-whenever-the-application-pool-of-iis-crashes-and-restart

Comment: @Paulo Thanks for response. This is more about generating event and debugging. Question is about how to detect an event has occurred and generate alerts.

Comment: Indeed, you want to monitor at runtime, maybe something like https://gist.github.com/KerryRitter/7bf65023a3dc6122f981

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own app but the values exist in the System EventLog after you have configured the application pool to log the various events there and just use off the shelf software to notify you.  We use Corner Bowl and just have it email us when certain entries are detected in that log area.  Things like Throttling and virtual memory limit hit are what we respond to.